# Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel. Can anyone tell me how should I write this query in laravel query builder ?

```
SELECT users.id, customers.zip
FROM users, customers
WHERE users.id =26
AND customers.customer_id = users.user_name
```

Comment: I read their manual but I couldn't figure it out. :(

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is with the query builder - [here's a link to a join example](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins)

As you develop your knowledge of Laravel, you'll likely start using Laravel's Eloquent ORM, in which case you'll want to [read this section of the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) to learn how to define relationships between tables.

Update:

I've see your comment above above, about not being able to understand the docs. That's surprising because they're well-tested and clear in this area, but here's answer I think you're looking for:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.id', '=', 26)
    ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'users.user_name')
    ->select('users.id', 'customers.zip');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')
->join('customers','users.username', '=', 'customer.customer_id')
->select('users.id', 'customer.zip')
->where('users.id','=', '26')
->get();
```

this will for you.

refer this for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

if you want to use eloquent collections refer this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter.

Answer (score 0):

Well In your case is better to use HasOne relationship http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships
You need to create Customer class

```
 class Customer extends Eloquent {

   //if you table is not called customers you need to add
    protected $table = 'table_name';

    }
```

Than in User controller

```
class User extends Eloquent {

        public function customers()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('Customer', 'customer_id');
        }

    }
```

In a nutshell laravel will find users.id(26) and join them with customer_id(26), it's easier and simpler less code in controller.

```
$user_id = 26; 
$user = User::find($user_id);

echo "username:".$user->user_name."user/customer zip code: ".$user->customers->zip;
```

This relationship is only if each user has one record in customers table(so if there will be twoo user_id 26 it will get only the first) if you want to have them more then one record for each user you need to use hasMany

Answer (score 0):

> DB::table('users as u1')
> ->join('customers as c1', 'c1.customer_id', '=', 'u1.user_name')
> ->->where('users.id', '=', 26)
> ->select('users.id', 'customers.zip');